# A Riley you can count on

Tags: riddle, wordplay

My prefix is quite definite.
My suffix lets you dream a bit.
My infix leaves it up to you.
In total, I am proved and true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My prefix is quite definite.

> **THE**, definite article.

My suffix lets you dream a bit.

> **REM**, sleep stage

My infix leaves it up to you.

> **OR**, signifying choice

In total, I am proved and true.

> **THEOREM**

Comment: Wow, that was quick. I can't yet accept.

Comment: Ohh, that rapid eye movement stuff. I got stuck on that one